a smartphone with sensors that can determine if there is someone alive near 1.5m distance?
a smartphone with sensors that can determine if there is someone alive near 1.5m distance?
I am looking for a hardware that has sensors that can detect vital signs while staying near people, like (not necessarily all possible, just one could suffice):

Temperature (infra red).
Pulse rate (camera may be).
Blood pressure (?).
Respiratory rate (camera and microphone may be).
Blood oxygen (??).

the specified sensors is what I know, but there probably are others that are better.
1.5m is just a thought, some ppl dont like the smarphone to be too near when they go sleep, but I think some sensors would require be be touching the body to work.
An app could then link the sensor with healthcare providers or a health insurance central.
It could also be an arduino or raspberry pi, but the point is to be a hardware that will surely be with the person most of the time, and an smartphone is almost granted to be. Unless it could be easy/safe to stay connected to the smartphone all the time.
I am not talking about:

the difficulties of letting such hardware work properly,
to let it work as intended,
or the software to be reliable
and the difficulties about the other side (healthcare) may face with imprecise detections
or the battery consumption (why batteries are so small? I just glued a battery bank on my smartphone..)

I am just looking for the hardware that has as much vital signs sensors as possible.

Another possibility:
A fitness tracker (a water diving proof one) could be connected to the smartphone to provide the special healthcare alert feature thru some complex app, the fitness tracker would be only bluetooth, minimal software, sensors and battery.
The real problem with wrist fitness trackers is the battery... Having to remove from the wrist to charge just breaks the whole point...
So a way to not have to remove it from the wrist would be the best option, may be 2 batteries, and it would use only one battery per time while we charge the other battery, this could work! any other idea? may be some wireless charger?

What's your use case? Is a smartwatch or other fitness tracker nonviable? You usually need skin contact or close to it for everything on that list except temperature, and even that's better with skin contact. There are plenty of commercially available products in wearable form factors that'll do all this, but few in a phone form.

mmm... the fitness tracker (a water diving proof one) could be connected to the smartphone to provide the special healthcare alert feature. The real problem with wrist fitness trackers is the battery... Having to remove from the wrist to charge is just breaks the whole point... But that idea is good, as long it becomes possible to never have to remove the fitness tracker from the wrist. Any idea about that?

I think any device (on or off body) will need to charge at some point if you want it to be wireless. The Garmin Vivofit 4 will go for like a year without charging, and only requires a battery swap, so something like that might work for you.
